# Wordpress 4.0 Forces entire site into SSL

Tags: ssl

I updated to Wordpress 4.0 last night and this morning I noticed something strange. when I go to my site at www.mysiteurl.com it automatically goes to HTTPS. Before the update, if I went to www.mysiteurl.com it kept it at HTTP which is the way I would like it to stay.

I read that Wordpress 4.0 makes some updates to how Wordpress handles SSL.

The thing is, I found out about this happening, by using the Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger. These are the errors it gave me:

```
Circular Redirect Path  Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).
Could Not Follow Redirect   URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.

To find the object, these are the redirects we had to follow
original    http://www.mysiteurl.com/
301 https://www.mysiteurl.com/
og:url  http://www.mysiteurl.com/
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: what is your website url? also, have you tried disabling all plugins and switching to a default theme?